# Wrong size from UITableView.SizeThatFits()

Tags: ios, uitableview, xamarin.ios

I implemented an UIPopoverController which is filled with a grouped UITableView. The number of cells in the table view can change dynamicly as long the popover is invisible. As soon as the popover becomes visible, the number of cells are fixed.

When the popover becomes visible, i resize the popover content to the height of the table view. I use the SizeThatFits() method from the UITableView to get the table size and use this value to set the popover PopoverContentSize height.

This works fine when the app is running. But always the first time the popover is shown after a new start of the app, SizeThatFits() delivers a wrong height (about 60 pixel to high). Has anyone an idea what this problem could be?

Comment: Did you solve this? I'm seeing the same issue right now (40 pixel higher in viewDidLoad than what I get in viewWillAppear... but at viewWillAppear it's too late to size the popover). I suspect it's due to the fact that during the initial call, the UITableView isn't yet inside an already-loaded navigation controller, and maybe sizeThatFits tries to do something clever in this case like accounting for the height of a navigation bar

Answer (score 3):

I had a somewhat similar issue because I was performing my calculations in ViewDidLoad. I was able to work around the issue by creating a bool flag in the view's code and only performing the calculations in ViewDidAppear if the flag was not set (and, of course setting the flag so that the logic wasn't repeated each time).

Comment: I second that. You won't get reliable dimensions in LoadView() or ViewDidLoad(). The first callback where they are correect is ViewWillAppear(). Just put your code in there and it will work.

Comment: I've already tested this solution. The size was in fact always correctly calculated in ViewWillAppear. But the Popover has never taken the values correctly, regardless of whether I set PopoverContentSize directly or I used the SetPopoverContentSize method.
The Popover is called by the PresentFromBarButtonItem in a Toolbar. Then ViewWillAppear is called by the iOS, where the size is set. It looks like the Popover did not accept size changes after it was called by PresentFromBarButtonItem. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

On iOS 5 and up, sizeThatFits on a UITableView gives the correct result when called within the viewDidLayoutSubviews UIViewController method.